# If text matches string and if text does not match string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 'some text' in a list and if this matches then I am showing select options in .input-1 dropdown, but what I cannot get to work is the opposite where it does not match the string. In this case, I want to hide the select options.

The first part of the code works, but second else if fails

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
$('.input-1 option').each(function() {
var ourOption = $(this).text().toLowerCase(); // convert text to Lowercase
var str = "Some Text";
var res = str.toLowerCase();
if (ourOption.match(res)) {
$(this).css('display', 'block');
}
else if (!ourOption.match(res)) {
$(this).css('display', 'none');
}   
})
});
```

The current result is that all options are hidden regardless of the matched text so I'm guessing there is an error in my else if or the syntax for no match is incorrect.

Comment: String matching function in javascript doesn't return true or false, but it returns the matched string.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this with an alternate function that can return via true false?

Comment: As DJ Yadav commented the match() is not meant to compare text, it is meant to find the match and it returns the matched text. You just need a == or === comparison.

Comment: @glennyboy can you update the question with some sample strings ?

Comment: The strings are dynamically populated in a repeat region. They do have caps which is why I dropped to lowercase.

Comment: Examples would be 'Reading' 'Maidenhead' 'London' - regions in the UK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.match() is to find a match in string, not compare and return true/false. You need comparison == here:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
 $('.input-1 option').each(function() {
  var ourOption = $(this).text().toLowerCase(); // convert text to Lowercase
  var str = "Some Text";
  var res = str.toLowerCase();
  if (ourOption.indexOf(res) > -1) {
    $(this).css('display', 'block');
  }
  else {
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
  }   
 })
});
```

As a matter of fact you do not even need an else-if here, just else is enough... because there are only 2 possibilities true  and false and both are covered with if/else.

Comment: you might need to add a return false to the if statement to break out of the each method

Comment: That seems to hide all options regardless of a text match

Comment: Do you have an option where text is "some text" ?

Comment: It just needs to contain that string so it could be 'Some Text and then carries on the string' - in that case, the option with that text should hide

Comment: Whoaaa! that is a different story now. You said you want to match the text. What you want is indexOf() method. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @Nawed Khan The match now seems to be too specific and some of the options are showing and others are hiding. Is there a way to qualify the match say with the first 5 characters for the match?

Comment: Use .substr(0, 5) to get first five characters of any string. We are now going off topic from the question :)

Comment: I didn't think it was off topic, but for example, my test string in the repeat region is 'London (Central)', but the Text in the Dropdown is just 'London' so that would be hidden, but it should be visible.

Comment: if (ourOption.indexOf(res.substr(0, 5)) > -1) {...} should match only the first 5 characters of your text in the options text.

Comment: @Naweed Khan could you have a crack at this follow-on query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56080848/check-select-for-text-hide-options-containing-text-if-more-than-3-options-and-c please....