# Check Select for text, hide options containing text if more than 3 options and change text on first select for no options

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a bit similar to my original question although not quite the same as [If text matches string and if text does not match string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56065893/if-text-matches-string-and-if-text-does-not-match-string/56066013#56066013).

In this instance what I want to do is check a Select for text AND that also has more than 3 options (as my CMS demands more than 1 so I need 2 dummy 'Default 1, Default 2' values), cross-browser hide options containing text 'Default' in a 'span' and change text on the first select for no options.

The first part of the if statement works by hiding the Options with 'Default x' text (if present) on browsers and iOS, but the 'No Options' text for the first select is applying to all 'selects' for the second part.

Have tried 'closest' and 'parent', but closest selects all 'selects' and I only want it applied to those explicitly that follow the if && rules.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  $('select option').each(function() {
    var ourOption = $(this).text().toLowerCase(); // convert text to Lowercase
    var str = "Default";
    var res = str.toLowerCase();

    if ((ourOption.indexOf(res) > -1) && ($(this).parent('select').has('option').length < 3)) {
      $(this).wrap('<span>'); // hide 'Default' options on iphone
      $(this).closest('select').find('option:nth-child(1)').text('Currently No Trial Classes'); // is currently applying to all selects?
    }

  })

});
</script>
```

Also tried

```
<script>

jQuery(document).ready( function() {

  $('select').each(function() {

 $('select option').each(function() {
  var ourOption = $(this).text().toLowerCase(); // convert text to Lowercase
  var str = "Default";
  var res = str.toLowerCase();
  var length = $(this).parent('select'); 

   if ((ourOption.indexOf(res) > -1) && (length.has('option').length < 3) ) {

    $(this).wrap('<span>'); // hide on iphone
 $(length).find('option:nth-child(1)').text('Currently No Trial Classes'); // is currently applying to all selects?
}
})
 }) 
});
</script>
```

Desired behaviour on 'Select' (note multiple selects need to be targeted)

**If there are options other than 'Default x'**

```
<select class="input input-select w-select" required="">
<option selected="" value="">Select Class</option>
<span><option>Default 1</option></span> 
<span><option>Default 2</option></span>
<option>Mayfair</option>
<option>Marylebone</option>
<option>London Bridge</option>
</select>
```

**If there are no options other than 'Default x'**

```
<select class="input input-select w-select" required="">
<option selected="" value="">Currently No Trial Classes</option>
<span><option>Default 1</option></span> 
<span><option>Default 2</option></span>
</select>
```

Comment: Please post your sample select HTML and the desired output

Comment: @Eddie - I've added the desired behaviour for the multiple 'selects'

Comment: So basically remove the non `Default` option?

Comment: No, the default dummy select options will always be there and need to be hidden, but the desired outcome will change the first select text if there are no other options (more than 3) past the default x2. So both HTML outputs above are valid depending on the number of options past the default 2.